# can we have browse option in html5 video player

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I want a page in that a video player plays my computer's video. I searched a lot on internet but with no result I am posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use code such as in the examples here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ to read one or more files. you can then read the file into a blob and pass it to the video player.

The reason for this slightly convoluted solution is that for security reasons the path isn't exposed in the File object so you can't simply reference the source on the local machine.